# Как удалить часть тэгов на js при условии, что…?

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="left-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="block-categories hidden-sm-down">
    <ul class="category-top-menu">
      <li><a class="text-uppercase h6" href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section class="background socialx">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="block-social col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="socialxtext">We Are Social</h2>
        <ul class="social-btns">
          <li class="btnx facebook">
            <a class="facebook faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx twitter">
            <a class="twitter faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Twitter"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx rss">
            <a class="rss faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Rss"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx youtube">
            <a class="youtube faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="YouTube"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx googleplus">
            <a class="googleplus faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Google +"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx pinterest">
            <a class="pinterest faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Pinterest"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx vimeo">
            <a class="vimeo faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Vimeo"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="btnx instagram">
            <a class="instagram faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Instagram"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Как написать на js: Если в `div` с `id="left-column"` содержится `section` с `class="background"`, тогда удалить этот тэг, но те тэги что внутри остались? 
Как написать на js: Если в `div` с `id="left-column"` содержится `section` с `class="background"` и `div` с классом `"content-wrapper"`, тогда удалить этоти тэги, но те тэги которые внутри этих, остались?

Comment: Надо взять элемент, который хотите удалить ... склонировать всех его детей... удалить его... клонированных детей вставить назад, я так думаю..

Comment: @Дмытрык клонировать ничего не надо, они при вставке в другое место просто перемещаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как искать элементы вам уже ответили в предыдущем вопросе.

**UPD**: Я там указал простейший вариант `moveTags(...)`, но лучше после родительского тега определить `nextSibling` и перемещать элементы с помощью `Node.insertBefore(...)`, тогда при любом раскладе они попадут в то же месторасположение.

```js
console.log( 'Было элементов: ', document.querySelectorAll( '*' ).length );

// Пример переноса элементов
function moveTags ( from, to ) {
    while ( from.firstChild ) {
        to.appendChild( from.firstChild );
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll( '#left-column section.background' ).forEach( el => {
    el.querySelectorAll( 'div.content-wrapper' ).forEach( d => {
        moveTags( d, el.parentElement );
        d.parentElement.removeChild( d );
    } );
    el.parentElement.removeChild( el );
} );

console.log( 'Осталось элементов: ', document.querySelectorAll( '*' ).length );
```

```html
<div id="left-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="block-categories hidden-sm-down">
        <ul class="category-top-menu">
            <li><a class="text-uppercase h6" href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section class="background socialx">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="block-social col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="socialxtext">We Are Social</h2>
                <ul class="social-btns">
                    <li class="btnx facebook"> <a class="facebook faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Facebook"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx twitter"><a class="twitter faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Twitter"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx rss"><a class="rss faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Rss"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx youtube"><a class="youtube faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="YouTube"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx googleplus"><a class="googleplus faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Google +"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx pinterest"><a class="pinterest faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Pinterest"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx vimeo"><a class="vimeo faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Vimeo"></a></li>
                    <li class="btnx instagram"><a class="instagram faf" href="#" target="_blank" title="Instagram"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

PS: и лучше не копировать весь ваш код в вопрос, а уменьшать его до минимального и нормально отформатировать. Никому не хочется смотреть на вот эти "макароны"

Comment: это понятно. Но, не все могут понять к примеру как вы по каким-то причинам. С этой целью, только. ПС: код был длиннее, я его и так порезал)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B0