# Горизонтальная прокрутка работает колесиком мышки. Как сделать аналог свайпом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой блок с горизонтальной прокруткой контента. Если использовать колесик мышки, то контент разделенный на колонки, плавно переходит от одной колонки к другой, ровно перелистывается информация колесиком.
В js добавлен свайп...
Как сделать, чтобы через свайп Влево/Вправо тоже можно было также плавно переходит с одной колонки на другую, как если бы использовать колесик мыши?

```js
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorizontal = true;
  var that = this;
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);
  
  var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
      actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;
  
  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorizontal = false;
  }
  
}

function getColumnWidth(that){
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
  var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
  var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
  return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
      distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
      defaultScrollShift = 30,
      savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
      scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;
  
  if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
  }else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
  }
  
  if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
    that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
    return true;
  }
  
  if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
  return false;
}

                        
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
    for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
      elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
    }
  });
});

// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!xDown || !yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientX: xUp,
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const xDiff = xDown - xUp;
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const xDiffAbs = Math.abs(xDown - xUp);
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(xDiffAbs, yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }

  if (xDiffAbs > yDiffAbs) {
    if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
      console.log('left');
    } else {
      console.log('right');
    }
  } else {
    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      console.log('up');
    } else {
      console.log('down');
    }
  }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}



.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}



.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}


article.mario {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
/*article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  column-width: 100vw;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}*/
article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  


  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="poscustomtext"><article class="mario"><div class="customtext">
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/abca98b122166092.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/abca98b1/22166092_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В ту пору, когда&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;была анонсирована, мода на стелс-экшены только-только начинала зарождаться, и любой мало-мальски приличный проект, хоть как-то позволяющий игроку бесшумно расправляться с неприятелями, сразу же нарекали “слелсом” и сталкивали лоб в лоб с&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Solid</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Это только потом выяснится, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;вообще-то есть много и от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, и даже от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Driver</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Да и сама по себе боевая система, включая знаменитую (да-да, ту самую, что позже будет популяризована не без помощи&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil 4</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) камеру из-за плеча, куда ближе к&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, нежели детищу&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Konami</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Но маркетинг ведь - штука сродни эпидемии: что надуют в ушко - в то и уверуешь.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И все было бы ничего, кабы датой релиза не значился конец 2001-го, а в качестве целевой платформы не был бы выбран Dreamcast. Тут даже к Ванге не ходи, чтобы понять всю абсурдность подобного решения - от консоли в ту пору уже публично открестилась даже сама&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Sega</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, а мир с замиранием сердца ждал релиза второй части похождений Снейка. Неудивительно, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;в итоге сыграли три с половиной человека, а про вышедший спустя полгода PS2-порт львиная доля владельцев данной консоли даже и не слыхивала.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">А жаль, ведь игра вполне себе могла претендовать на лавры одного из лучших консольных экшенов того поколения. Что еще интереснее - перед нами практически уникальный пример проекта, на 80% состоящего из откровенной копипасты, но при этом умело связанной в единое и уж очень гармоничное целое. Причем, как это ни странно, даже обладающего своим узнаваемым лицом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/ef190be422166093.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/ef190be4/22166093_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И хотя разработкой занималась никому доселе не известная шведская студия&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, высоко задранную планку качества ощущаешь уже с первых минут. Оркестровые мотивы за авторством&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Ричарда Жака</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;(британского композитора, к тому времени уже сделавшего себе громкое имя благодаря внушительному списку “сеговских” проектов) пробирают до глубины души. FMV-вставки с “живыми” актерами, стилизованные под новостную сводку, удивляют не на шутку. Равно как и агитационные плакаты, которые можно наблюдать на экране загрузок.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Но вот уж где геймера ждет настоящий шок, так это на поприще графики. Великолепные модели персонажей (удивило разве что отсутствие мимики, да и сами лица объективно слабее, чем в той же&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Code Veronica</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) и потрясающая детализация окружения, которую ранее, в основном, можно было наблюдать лишь на рендренных фонах - вот чего точно не следовало ожидать от безвестной команды шведов. Движок при этом очень редко дает сбои в виде просадки fps, а сама по себе картинка смотрится очень гладкой и четкой.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Слегка придя в себя от поросячьего восторга, начинаешь разбираться в деталях сюжета. В принципе, ничего из ряда вон здесь игра уже предложить не может. Завязка достаточно стандартна - по крайней мере, если проводить аналогии с художественными фильмами. Главный герой в лице Джека Вейда просыпается в госпитале, где встречается с дочерью убитого основателя ACN - крупнейшей корпорации, служащей законодательным органом будущего. Принципы ее функционирования очень просты - группа специальных агентов, именуемых “хэдхантерами”, выслеживает опаснейших преступников, после чего берет под стражу и отправляет в подводную тюрьму. Там провинившимся супостатам предлагается принять участие в гладиаторской битве на арене. В случае проигрыша ACN имеет право распорядиться внутренними органами потерпевшего фиаско человека на свое усмотрение.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Когда-то Джек и сам был “охотником за головами”, причем номером один. Именно поэтому Энджи и просит нашего героя помочь ей в расследовании убийства. Вот только те самые загадочные события, что привели Джека к больничной койке и амнезии, послужили причиной аннулирования “хэдхантерской” лицензии. Так что, процесс сбора мозаики под названием “Убийство Кристофера Штерна” придется объединить с так называемым “возвращением в школу”.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Поначалу сюжет развивается довольно-таки плавно. В лучших традициях&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;основную массу ключевых фактов можно подцепить не из роликов (здесь они представлены как в виде кат-сцен на движке, так и CG-видео), а при помощи различных документов и записок, так что не ленитесь осматривать каждый уголок. Однако ближе к финалу вектор развития кардинально сменится, шагнув от былого (уж простите за небольшой спойлер) футуристического детектива в сторону научной фантастики с характерными для нее нотками антиутопии.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/322911f922166094.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/322911f9/22166094_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">С точки же зрения геймплея,</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp;Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;представляет собой достаточно интересный симбиоз сразу нескольких проектов, названия которых были обозначены в самом начале статьи. Передвижение между ключевыми точками осуществляется верхом на байке, модель управления которым достаточно своеобразна. Да и сам город отличается на редкость убогой проработкой - страшненькие здания с размазанными текстурками, полнейшее отсутствие интерактивности и жителей на улицах. Что таким образом пытались нам показать разработчики - решительно непонятно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Основное же действие будет разворачиваться на локациях закрытого типа, как правило отличающихся внушительными размерами. Набор самый стандартный: заправка, офисное здание, морской порт, торговый центр. В ряде случаев будет необходимо решить какую-нибудь головоломку, как правило построенную на стандартном скелете “возьми предмет там и примени его здесь”. В общем, ничего особенного - поклонники&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Silent Hill</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;и&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;справятся в два счета.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Куда интереснее дела обстоят с экшен-составляющей, изрядно смахивающей на серию&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Герой достаточно подвижен - например, может лихо троллить своих врагов, перекатываясь из стороны в сторону. Да, сейчас это уже никого не удивляет, но тогда смотрелось вполне себе в новинку. Вы, конечно же, не поверите, но одной из первых игр (самой первой, если что, был дремучий экшен&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">WinBack</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;1999 года розлива) с пресловутой возможностью стрелять из-за угла или баррикад стала именно&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunder</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Арсенал у Джека самый стандартный - пистолет, дробовик, автомат, гранатомет и еще парочка взрывоопасных экземпляров. Единственное новаторство - это пустые гильзы, которые можно использовать для привлечения врагов. Правда, рассчитать траекторию полета оных с высокой точностью порой оказывается достаточно трудно, так что назвать все эту затею хорошей и удобной язык не повернется. Лучше уж старое-доброе “снейковское” простукивание стен.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">К слову, о&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Soild</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. В игре есть ровным счетом три незначительных момента, которые, собственно, и роднят детище&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Кодзимы</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;с нашим пациентом. Первое - стелс-миссии, с которыми придется регулярно иметь дело в процессе получения лицензий. Тут уж действительно настоящий "стелс" - никакого оружия кроме собственных рук, с помощью которых Джек не прочь свернуть вражескую шею и вышеупомянутые гильзы. Второе - это оформление самой виртуальной реальности, внутри которой и будет проходить выполнение тестов. Наконец, последнее - это часы с возможностью совершения видеозвонка. Эдакий продвинутый вариант знаменитого кодека.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И, наконец, отдельным пунктом хотелось выделить боссов, в работе над которыми&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">постаралась как следует. Особой харизмой здешние злодеи похвастаться не могут, однако куда важнее для нас тот факт, что каждая битва строго уникальна и требует сугубо индивидуального подхода к тому или иному супостату. Никакой рутиной в духе “хоровод вокруг громилы с последующим “спусканием” в его тушку всего имеющегося арсенала” здесь не пахнет и подавно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/fa38ef5422166095.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362397/fa38ef54/22166095_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Подводя итоги, хочется сказать, что судьба&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;все же очень печальна. Конечно, даже с натяжкой игра не способна называться хитом, поскольку мелких огрехов хватает и в геймплее, и сюжете. Да и сама по себе концепция, отличающаяся засильем клише, все-таки не может претендовать на значимые лавры. В то же время, перед нами очень качественный проект, который вполне мог бы принести своим создателям больше денег, а для владельцев PS2 и DC стать куда более значимым (в плане известности) подарком, нежели он является. Хотя, впрочем, лучше уж быть эдаким lost treasure, чем служить пустым местом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">***</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И напоследок… о сиквеле замолвите слово.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В 2004-м году на PS2 и Xbox вышло продолжение под названием&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, действие которого разворачивалось спустя 20 лет с момента окончания оригинальной игры. За прошедшие годы виртуальный мир сильно изменился - теперь это уже был чистейший киберпанк с присущими для него неоновыми небоскребами, а нотки антиутопии заиграли еще сильнее. Как итог - жителей города распределили между двумя кастами, низшей и высшей.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Несмотря на ряд объективных достоинств, плохого в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">было куда больше. Это и невнятный сюжет, и странное управление с какой-то совершенно недекватной системой прицеливания. Наконец, сменив сеттинг, игра сильно сдала в плане разнообразия локаций. Да и сам по себе графический движок по меркам 2004 года смотрелся просто достойно, но не более того.</span></p>
</div></article></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div></div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все точно так-же, как и с колесиком. Но у вас еще проблема, когда нажать на сам скролл мышкой у вас уже так плавно не переходит. Это также устраняется прибавлением нужной ширины начального слайда.

Comment: Это да. можно колесик имитировать свайпом?

Comment: я понял вроде вас. вы имеете ввиду если делать свайп, то будет прокрутка во время свайпа пальцем, затем как сработает свайп то криво будет перелистование. тогда лучше реализовать это кнопками.

Comment: Причем тут это? Формула расчета должна работать на ширину слайда.

Comment: @And https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960283 Если мне, кто-то сделает оба варианта вместе (чтобы в одном файле были оба). Наставлю плюсов тому во всех темах.

Comment: Вы не понимаете алгоритм работы скрипта? Взяли его со стороны?

Comment: @And кое-что со стороны. но, сути это не меняет. Вопрос актуальный. В скрипте работа с колесиком мыши, мне нужен аналог для свайпа и кнопок.

Comment: Может мой вопрос непонятен?

Comment: Учите мат часть, вам никто ничего не должен и даже не обязан отвечать и писать за вас код. Я уже ответил вам, что вам нужно сделать, а делать это за вас никто не будет. У вас есть 4 положения 1. колесико, 2. тач, 3. мышь, 4. стрелки клавиатуры. Вам нужно сделать одну функцию, для расчета ширины по которой при прокрутке, клике или перетаскивании, будет переходить к новой ширине, которая будет рассчитана в зависимости от количества изображений в стопке. Тогда не будет такого, что я могу сдвинуть лишь пиксель.

Comment: `Я повторюсь, я не программист по js` с этого и надо было начинать. - Учите мат часть.

Comment: @And если бы я мог самостоятельно сделать, то не написал бы. В коде даны условия для колесика с переменными. Я не углублялся в программирование js.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev тут проблема в психологическом аспекте. Мы готовы помочь человеку, в некоторых случаях даже написать код за него, если чувствуется, что человек хочет разобраться, вникнуть в суть. Если у человека подход - я не собираюсь углубляться, сделайте за меня, то помогать неохота.

Comment: Есть библиотека которая может в прокрутку свайпом, колесом и кнопками https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html

Comment: хммм, как же вы тогда создаете сложные сайты на любой cms? в 2019 без `js` ну уж очень сложно обойтись, а вообще, вам с таким запросом на фрилансер, ибо вы хотите что бы сделали за вас. Вы так и говорите, что не углубляетесь в `js`, тогда просто закажите услугу. Это за 100-200 рублей за пол часа сделают вам, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Я разбираю код на логическом уровне. И некоторое я уже имею писать на js. Помогать или нет - конечно дело ваше. Вы так мне пишите, будто я заставляю кого-то. Но, это ведь не так. И я не понимаю - зачем писать такое, когда можно просто промолчать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Nick Я вижу, что вы хотели мне помочь. Но. Такая библиотека не годиться. Подобных библиотек «Слайдерных много»: Свайпер, Овл, Слик и пр. Но, они работают строго с контейнером. В данном случае прокрутка уникальная в отличие от библиотек, потому что количество окон автоматизируются под контент в зависимости от ширины экрана и объема информации, а не наоборот, как в библиотеках.

Comment: @ThisMan Отвечу кратко. Создавать конструкции - это инженерная часть. Программировать - программная. Я многое уже умею на js/jq, но они то не в ответе за инженерную часть. js - это язык программирования, который работает на ваших компах.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Мы сделали это. Я настоятельно прошу всех вас убрать минуса, если вы такое делали.

Comment: @And Я настоятельно прошу всех вас убрать минуса, если вы такое делали.

Comment: @ThisMan Я настоятельно прошу всех вас убрать минуса, если вы такое делали.

Comment: @Nick Я настоятельно прошу всех вас убрать минуса, если вы такое делали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за написание функции «horizontalClick» **alex Roosso**
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/331743/alex-roosso

Горизонтальная прокрутка контента. В данной версии реализовано:

1) Прокрутка контента колёсиком мыши, когда курсор мыши находить в области блока с контентом.

2) Прокрутка контента кнопками (желтые кнопки слева и справа).

3) Прокрутка контента с помощью технологии Свайп на сенсорных устройствах.

4) Прокрутка контента с помощью стрелок клавиатуры (стрелки: влево/вправо).

Код черновой. Поэтому, если у вас есть решения лучше, буду рад вашим предложениям.

Рабочий пример:

```js
function horizontalScroll(e){
isHorizontal = true;
var that = this;
that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);
  
var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;
  
if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
} else {
isHorizontal = false;
}
}

function horizontalClick(that, to){
isHorizontal = true;

that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

var actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
targetColumn = actualColumn + to;

if(!scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
isHorizontal = false;
}
}

function getColumnWidth(that){
var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
defaultScrollShift = 30,
savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;
  
if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
}else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
}
  
if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
return true;
}
  
if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
var scx = document.getElementById( 'screenx' );
var i;
for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
} else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
}

$("#next").on('click', function() {
horizontalClick(elems[0], 1);
});

$("#prev").on('click', function() {
horizontalClick(elems[0], -1);
});
  
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

scx.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

scx.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
if (!xDown || !yDown) {
return;
}

const {
clientX: xUp,
clientY: yUp
} = getTouch(e);
const xDiff = xDown - xUp;
const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
const xDiffAbs = Math.abs(xDown - xUp);
const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

// at least <offset> are a swipe
if (Math.max(xDiffAbs, yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
return;
}

if (xDiffAbs > yDiffAbs) {
if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
horizontalClick(elems[0], -1);
} else {
horizontalClick(elems[0], 1);
}
} else {
if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
console.log('up');
} else {
console.log('down');
}
}
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
switch (e.which) {
case 37: // left
horizontalClick(elems[0], -1);
break;

case 39: // right
horizontalClick(elems[0], 1);
break;

default:
return; // exit this handler for other keys
}

e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});  

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
}
});
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
/*.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}*/
.background:first-child {
  /*background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kXq9Qmnj/bgd1.jpg);*/
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
          transform: translateY(-15vh);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/W14vywqg/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TY0xQ41T/photo-1433840496881-cbd845929862.jpg);
}
/* Set stacking context of slides */
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.background:nth-child(3) .content-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
    transform: translateY(40vh);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}


#prev {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
 z-index: 9;
}
#next {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
 z-index: 9;
}

article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.customtext {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bsb {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
  <section class="background" id="screenx">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="poscustomtext"><div id="prev"></div><div id="next"></div><article class="mario"><div class="customtext">
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/abca98b122166092.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/abca98b1/22166092_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В ту пору, когда&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;была анонсирована, мода на стелс-экшены только-только начинала зарождаться, и любой мало-мальски приличный проект, хоть как-то позволяющий игроку бесшумно расправляться с неприятелями, сразу же нарекали “слелсом” и сталкивали лоб в лоб с&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Solid</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Это только потом выяснится, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;вообще-то есть много и от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, и даже от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Driver</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Да и сама по себе боевая система, включая знаменитую (да-да, ту самую, что позже будет популяризована не без помощи&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil 4</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) камеру из-за плеча, куда ближе к&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, нежели детищу&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Konami</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Но маркетинг ведь - штука сродни эпидемии: что надуют в ушко - в то и уверуешь.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И все было бы ничего, кабы датой релиза не значился конец 2001-го, а в качестве целевой платформы не был бы выбран Dreamcast. Тут даже к Ванге не ходи, чтобы понять всю абсурдность подобного решения - от консоли в ту пору уже публично открестилась даже сама&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Sega</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, а мир с замиранием сердца ждал релиза второй части похождений Снейка. Неудивительно, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;в итоге сыграли три с половиной человека, а про вышедший спустя полгода PS2-порт львиная доля владельцев данной консоли даже и не слыхивала.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">А жаль, ведь игра вполне себе могла претендовать на лавры одного из лучших консольных экшенов того поколения. Что еще интереснее - перед нами практически уникальный пример проекта, на 80% состоящего из откровенной копипасты, но при этом умело связанной в единое и уж очень гармоничное целое. Причем, как это ни странно, даже обладающего своим узнаваемым лицом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/ef190be422166093.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/ef190be4/22166093_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И хотя разработкой занималась никому доселе не известная шведская студия&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, высоко задранную планку качества ощущаешь уже с первых минут. Оркестровые мотивы за авторством&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Ричарда Жака</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;(британского композитора, к тому времени уже сделавшего себе громкое имя благодаря внушительному списку “сеговских” проектов) пробирают до глубины души. FMV-вставки с “живыми” актерами, стилизованные под новостную сводку, удивляют не на шутку. Равно как и агитационные плакаты, которые можно наблюдать на экране загрузок.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Но вот уж где геймера ждет настоящий шок, так это на поприще графики. Великолепные модели персонажей (удивило разве что отсутствие мимики, да и сами лица объективно слабее, чем в той же&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Code Veronica</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) и потрясающая детализация окружения, которую ранее, в основном, можно было наблюдать лишь на рендренных фонах - вот чего точно не следовало ожидать от безвестной команды шведов. Движок при этом очень редко дает сбои в виде просадки fps, а сама по себе картинка смотрится очень гладкой и четкой.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Слегка придя в себя от поросячьего восторга, начинаешь разбираться в деталях сюжета. В принципе, ничего из ряда вон здесь игра уже предложить не может. Завязка достаточно стандартна - по крайней мере, если проводить аналогии с художественными фильмами. Главный герой в лице Джека Вейда просыпается в госпитале, где встречается с дочерью убитого основателя ACN - крупнейшей корпорации, служащей законодательным органом будущего. Принципы ее функционирования очень просты - группа специальных агентов, именуемых “хэдхантерами”, выслеживает опаснейших преступников, после чего берет под стражу и отправляет в подводную тюрьму. Там провинившимся супостатам предлагается принять участие в гладиаторской битве на арене. В случае проигрыша ACN имеет право распорядиться внутренними органами потерпевшего фиаско человека на свое усмотрение.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Когда-то Джек и сам был “охотником за головами”, причем номером один. Именно поэтому Энджи и просит нашего героя помочь ей в расследовании убийства. Вот только те самые загадочные события, что привели Джека к больничной койке и амнезии, послужили причиной аннулирования “хэдхантерской” лицензии. Так что, процесс сбора мозаики под названием “Убийство Кристофера Штерна” придется объединить с так называемым “возвращением в школу”.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Поначалу сюжет развивается довольно-таки плавно. В лучших традициях&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;основную массу ключевых фактов можно подцепить не из роликов (здесь они представлены как в виде кат-сцен на движке, так и CG-видео), а при помощи различных документов и записок, так что не ленитесь осматривать каждый уголок. Однако ближе к финалу вектор развития кардинально сменится, шагнув от былого (уж простите за небольшой спойлер) футуристического детектива в сторону научной фантастики с характерными для нее нотками антиутопии.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/322911f922166094.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/322911f9/22166094_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">С точки же зрения геймплея,</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp;Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;представляет собой достаточно интересный симбиоз сразу нескольких проектов, названия которых были обозначены в самом начале статьи. Передвижение между ключевыми точками осуществляется верхом на байке, модель управления которым достаточно своеобразна. Да и сам город отличается на редкость убогой проработкой - страшненькие здания с размазанными текстурками, полнейшее отсутствие интерактивности и жителей на улицах. Что таким образом пытались нам показать разработчики - решительно непонятно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Основное же действие будет разворачиваться на локациях закрытого типа, как правило отличающихся внушительными размерами. Набор самый стандартный: заправка, офисное здание, морской порт, торговый центр. В ряде случаев будет необходимо решить какую-нибудь головоломку, как правило построенную на стандартном скелете “возьми предмет там и примени его здесь”. В общем, ничего особенного - поклонники&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Silent Hill</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;и&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;справятся в два счета.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Куда интереснее дела обстоят с экшен-составляющей, изрядно смахивающей на серию&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Герой достаточно подвижен - например, может лихо троллить своих врагов, перекатываясь из стороны в сторону. Да, сейчас это уже никого не удивляет, но тогда смотрелось вполне себе в новинку. Вы, конечно же, не поверите, но одной из первых игр (самой первой, если что, был дремучий экшен&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">WinBack</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;1999 года розлива) с пресловутой возможностью стрелять из-за угла или баррикад стала именно&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunder</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Арсенал у Джека самый стандартный - пистолет, дробовик, автомат, гранатомет и еще парочка взрывоопасных экземпляров. Единственное новаторство - это пустые гильзы, которые можно использовать для привлечения врагов. Правда, рассчитать траекторию полета оных с высокой точностью порой оказывается достаточно трудно, так что назвать все эту затею хорошей и удобной язык не повернется. Лучше уж старое-доброе “снейковское” простукивание стен.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">К слову, о&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Soild</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. В игре есть ровным счетом три незначительных момента, которые, собственно, и роднят детище&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Кодзимы</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;с нашим пациентом. Первое - стелс-миссии, с которыми придется регулярно иметь дело в процессе получения лицензий. Тут уж действительно настоящий "стелс" - никакого оружия кроме собственных рук, с помощью которых Джек не прочь свернуть вражескую шею и вышеупомянутые гильзы. Второе - это оформление самой виртуальной реальности, внутри которой и будет проходить выполнение тестов. Наконец, последнее - это часы с возможностью совершения видеозвонка. Эдакий продвинутый вариант знаменитого кодека.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И, наконец, отдельным пунктом хотелось выделить боссов, в работе над которыми&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">постаралась как следует. Особой харизмой здешние злодеи похвастаться не могут, однако куда важнее для нас тот факт, что каждая битва строго уникальна и требует сугубо индивидуального подхода к тому или иному супостату. Никакой рутиной в духе “хоровод вокруг громилы с последующим “спусканием” в его тушку всего имеющегося арсенала” здесь не пахнет и подавно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/fa38ef5422166095.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362397/fa38ef54/22166095_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Подводя итоги, хочется сказать, что судьба&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;все же очень печальна. Конечно, даже с натяжкой игра не способна называться хитом, поскольку мелких огрехов хватает и в геймплее, и сюжете. Да и сама по себе концепция, отличающаяся засильем клише, все-таки не может претендовать на значимые лавры. В то же время, перед нами очень качественный проект, который вполне мог бы принести своим создателям больше денег, а для владельцев PS2 и DC стать куда более значимым (в плане известности) подарком, нежели он является. Хотя, впрочем, лучше уж быть эдаким lost treasure, чем служить пустым местом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">***</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И напоследок… о сиквеле замолвите слово.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В 2004-м году на PS2 и Xbox вышло продолжение под названием&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, действие которого разворачивалось спустя 20 лет с момента окончания оригинальной игры. За прошедшие годы виртуальный мир сильно изменился - теперь это уже был чистейший киберпанк с присущими для него неоновыми небоскребами, а нотки антиутопии заиграли еще сильнее. Как итог - жителей города распределили между двумя кастами, низшей и высшей.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Несмотря на ряд объективных достоинств, плохого в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">было куда больше. Это и невнятный сюжет, и странное управление с какой-то совершенно недекватной системой прицеливания. Наконец, сменив сеттинг, игра сильно сдала в плане разнообразия локаций. Да и сам по себе графический движок по меркам 2004 года смотрелся просто достойно, но не более того.</span></p>
</div></article></div>
    </div>
  </section>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: А теперь сделайте быстро вправо и влево стрелками.

Comment: @And да, есть подергивания. Есть предложение?

Comment: @And но, только псих будет резко нажимать. Однако, я уверен и на это есть решение. Не ставьте мне минусов. Я ведь запомню.

Comment: Тут не подергивание, тут залипание скрипта - это огромнейший **длинно-жирный минус**. К тому-же, данное решение никак не отвечает на ваш вопрос, ибо скроллинга и движения нет, уйдя от этого, вырезав скрипты, не значит, что сделано правильно.

Comment: @And Так если знаете как. То, пожалуйста, помогите создать решение.

Comment: Я не хочу переписывать за вас весь скрипт, если вас устраивает до-сих-пор залипание скрипта, пользуйтесь на здоровье, если не устраивает, копайте глубже. И кстати, повторюсь, - это не решение вашей задачи, так-как, нет скроллинга мышкой, нет кадровой анимации при щелчке или попытки перетянуть.

Comment: @And Пока то что есть достаточно. Спасибо за рекомендацию. Но на данное время у меня нет времени копаться js/jq программирование. В будущем - возможно. Но, если вы видите своё решение, то за какую цену бы вы его сделали?